# Calculated Field in Expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression, calculated-columns

I am using Fetch XML to get my results and cannot do the calculation on the query side. I need to take the difference on the SalesSum field and calculate based on the period and year.

Here is an example of my data

```
SalesSum    Period  Year
275000      1       2017
195000      2       2017
205000      3       2017
318000      1       2018
425250      2       2018
395000      3       2018
```

> Difference = ((SalesSum period 1 year 2018) - (SalesSum period1 year
>   2017))
>
> Example: Difference = 318000-270888=43000 Period 1 Year

can this be accomplished using an SSRS expression?

Comment: A few questions: Will there only ever be 2 years in your dataset or more? How are you going to show the results in your report (as there are different ways to calculate it dependent on your report layout). If you can update your question to show the expected output based on your sample data it will be easier to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tablix` and select just Period as a row group.

And write this formula as the expression.

```
= Sum(iif(Max(Fields!Year.Value)=Fields!Year.Value,Fields!SalesSum.Value,0)) 
      -  Sum(iif(Min(Fields!Year.Value)=Fields!Year.Value,Fields!SalesSum.Value,0))
```